# Как вычислить количество минут, зная начальное и конечное время

Tags: c#, winforms

Скорее всего это очень глупый вопрос....
Есть две строки обозначающие время начала и время конца:

```
string a = "00:50:00";
string b = "01:20:00";
```

Как, собственно говоря, мне вычислить сколько прошло минут между "a" и "b".

Прошу прощения, если это идиотский вопрос....

Comment: Переведи все значения в секунды, получи их разность и переведи её снова в минуты.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

За время в C# отвечает структура [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan), которая в свою очередь имеет все необходимое для вычисления нужного результата.

- Первым делом переведите ваш текст в `TimeSpan`:

  ```
  var aTime= TimeSpan.Parse(a);
  var bTime = TimeSpan.Parse(b);
  ```
- Дальше делайте необходимые вычисления:

  ```
  var result = bTime - aTime;
  ```

В результате вы получите 00:30:00 и тоже в `TimeSpan`.
Если надо вернуть обратно в `String`, то `.ToString()` в помощь.

---

Ваш формат времени довольно распространенный, но если он будет отличаться (например `00 50 00`), то стоит использовать метод [ParseExact()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact), который позволяет выставить необходимый формат.

Comment: `то стоит использовать метод ParseExact()` - либо [TryParseExact()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8), если не хотим бросать и отлавливать исключение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо огромное за подробный ответ